# Woman persecuted by body-possessing (possibly deceased) ex-boyfriend (published in Asimov's magazine circa 1990)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, urban-fantasy

I'm pretty sure I read this story in Asimov's magazine around 1990.  In it, a woman in modern America repeatedly has relationships with men who turn possessive and abusive, and eventually realizes that her first boyfriend has been taking over the bodies of successive boyfriends (he's literally "possessive").

Her life grows ever more difficult, since the pattern of her life leads people to think that she's lying, or at the very least, repeatedly falling for men of the same type.  I think the last boyfriend we see in the story is a police officer whom she met in the course of dealing with her-last-but-one boyfriend, which makes life even more difficult.  I don't recall how the story resolves, though she may have figured out a way to permanently defeat the villain.